# How to initialize a const std::vector with boost::assign::repeat with repeating elements?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

I have the following snippet of code:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

int main()
{
  const std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of(1).repeat(999, 1).repeat(1000, 2);
  BOOST_ASSERT(v.size() == 2000);
}
```

Which I would like to convert to something more like

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

int main()
{
  const std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::repeat(1000, 1).repeat(1000, 2); // illegal
  // or
  // const std::vector<int> v(1000,1).repeat(1000,2); // illegal
  BOOST_ASSERT(v.size() == 2000);
}
```

Is there some kind of adapter that I can use so that I do not need to use `boost::assign::list_of()` with one element and then `boost::assign::repeat`?

I have found a way to do this with `boost::assign::push_back()` but this way I cannot declare vector as `const`:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  boost::assign::push_back(v).repeat(1000, 1).repeat(1000, 2);
  BOOST_ASSERT(v.size() == 2000);
}
```

**EDIT**

So as suggested I have tried:

```
std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of<int>().repeat(1000, 3).repeat(1000, 2);
```

but this works only for non `const` initialization like above. I can use something like this though:

```
const std::vector<int> v = boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>().repeat(1000, 1).repeat(1000, 2);
```

Is that recommended?

Comment: I see there's an overload of `list_of` with 0 parameters. Does that work?

Comment: @chris I can but only for non `const` initialization. I can use `boost::assign_detail::generic_list` though (check my edit)

Comment: Looking at [this source](https://github.com/boostorg/assign/blob/develop/include/boost/assign/list_of.hpp#L592), I don't see how it wouldn't work for initializing a constant vector. However, it does look like it would prepend an extra 0.

Comment: may I ask why you're using boost.assign instead of using the iterator pair constructor with boost.iterator's counting and transform iterators?

Comment: @jaggedSpire can you show how to do this? I am not aware of this

Comment: @Patryk [sure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf9e09765442beda)